# Giving an app access to its own folder

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I've installed Android Studio in Program Files because I don't think programs belong anywhere else (installer asks to install under my `appdata` profile folder). However, whenever I try to update Android SDK I need to do it as administrator because otherwise the app cannot access its own folder.

This *might* be related to the fact that the SDK updater is a `.bat` file that runs a `.jar` file. Can I allow this file to change the contents of the directory without I having to run it as admin?

Comment: You shouldn't need Administrator access to create files in Program Files within the applications own directory.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't allow program run by normal-users to make changes in Program Files folder. It can be easily fixed though.

- Browse to the folder ( C:/Program Files/Android ) and select **Properties** from the context menu.
- Click on the **Security** tab and then click on the **Edit** button.
- Select **Users** (should be the second last option) from the list menu and check the **Full Control** checkmark.
- Press Ok.